# Keeping date and ID of "earliest" polygon following a dissolve of overlapping polygons

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

Currently I have two MULTIPOLYGON layers that I have dissolved into one layer in the following way:

```
sq = function(pt, sz = 1) st_polygon(list(rbind(c(pt - sz), c(pt[1] + sz, pt[2] - sz), c(pt + sz), c(pt[1] - sz, pt[2] + sz), c(pt - sz))))

# First Layer
flood1 = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(4.2,4.2)), sq(c(0,0)), sq(c(1, -0.8)), sq(c(0.5, 1.7)), sq(c(3,3)), sq(c(-3, -3))))
plot(flood1)

flood1$id <- c("5001", "5002", "5792", "5029", "4802", "6783")
flood1$date <- as.Date(as.Date("2011-12-30"):as.Date("2012-01-04"), origin="1970-01-01")

# Second Layer
flood2 = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(4.2,4.0)), sq(c(0,0.2)), sq(c(1.1, -0.6)), sq(c(0.8, 1.9)), sq(c(3.5,6)), sq(c(-3.4, -3.3))))
plot(flood2)

flood2$id <- c("5008", "6002", "7592", "5209", "1001", "4752")
flood2$date <- as.Date(as.Date("2014-12-30"):as.Date("2015-01-04"), origin="1970-01-01")

# Dissolving overlapping polygons together
flood_agg = sf::st_cast(st_union(flood1, flood2),"POLYGON")
```

Now, let's imagine each one of these polygons represents a different flood which happened during a monsoon season, while each layer represents a different monsoon season. After successfully dissolving overlapping polygons into one "flooded area", I would like to retain the Date and ID of the **earliest** flood that is a part of the dissolved group. The actual layers I'm working with contain around 2000 floods, so I need to figure out how to do this programmatically. Any thoughts on how I could go about this?

Comment: Looks like a good case for raster. You could rasterize everything 'terra::rasterize()', 'stars::st_rasterize()', 'fasterize::fasterize()'

Comment: Thanks, I'm new-ish to GIS research, you mind walking through that method in a bit more detail?

Comment: In the end I did as you started. No raster. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example of how to get it done. Let's construct an example with three layers, and simplify date/ID.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# function to make squares as example
sq = function(pt, sz = 1){st_polygon(list(rbind(c(pt - sz), c(pt[1] + sz, pt[2] - sz), c(pt + sz), c(pt[1] - sz, pt[2] + sz), c(pt - sz))))}

# First Layer (2012)
flood1 = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(4.2,4.2)), sq(c(0,0))))
st_geometry(flood1) <- "geometry"
flood1$id <- c("5001", "5002")
flood1$date <- as.Date("2012-01-01")

# Second Layer  (2013)
flood2 = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(3.2, 5.2)), sq(c(1,0))))
st_geometry(flood2) <- "geometry"
flood2$id <- c("6001", "6002")
flood2$date <- as.Date("2012-01-02")

# Third Layer (2014)
flood3 = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(4.2, 0.2)), sq(c(2,5))))
st_geometry(flood3) <- "geometry"
flood3$id <- c("7001", "7002")
flood3$date <- as.Date("2012-01-03")

# auxiliary function for clipping geometries
st_erase = function(x, y){st_difference(x, st_union(st_combine(y)))}

# clip what is left of day 2 on top of day one
flood2_add = st_erase(flood2, flood1)

# clip what is left of day 3 on top of the sum of day 1 and 2
flood3_add = st_erase(flood3, flood2_add)

# bring everything together
d <- rbind(flood1, flood2_add, flood3_add)

# just to facilitate the graph lets create a column factor dates
d$date_factor <- as.factor(d$date)

# erase duplicates
d$box <- NULL # we dont use box, let's erase it
d <- d %>% distinct()

# show me the money
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = d,
          aes(fill = date_factor),
          alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The oldest date gets to be on top.

Note that indeed they are not overlapping:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = d,
          aes(fill = date_factor),
          alpha = 0.3) +
  facet_wrap(~date_factor) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

We can inspect the data.frame to see if we got the results we want:

```
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -1 ymin: -1 xmax: 5.2 ymax: 6.2
CRS:           NA
    id       date date_factor                       geometry
1 5001 2012-01-01  2012-01-01 POLYGON ((3.2 3.2, 5.2 3.2,...
2 5002 2012-01-01  2012-01-01 POLYGON ((-1 -1, 1 -1, 1 1,...
3 6001 2012-01-02  2012-01-02 POLYGON ((2.2 4.2, 2.2 6.2,...
4 6002 2012-01-02  2012-01-02 POLYGON ((2 1, 2 -1, 1 -1, ...
5 7001 2012-01-03  2012-01-03 POLYGON ((3.2 1.2, 5.2 1.2,...
6 7002 2012-01-03  2012-01-03 POLYGON ((3 4, 1 4, 1 6, 2....
```

Looks fine to me! We have the date and the ID from the cropped features. Now, you still will have to adapt this inside of a custom function, to be able to use it 2000 times (a `for loop`, a `apply` function or with my favorite `purrr`).

Note that we have six features, becouse there are several IDs on the same date. If we were to dissolve everything by date (ignoring ID) we could do:

```
d1 <- d %>% 
  group_by(date_factor) %>% 
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = d1,
          aes(fill = date_factor),
          alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = element_blank()) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Which looks the same as before, but with only three features.

```
Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -1 ymin: -1 xmax: 5.2 ymax: 6.2
CRS:           NA

date_factor <fctr> geometry <S3: sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>
2012-01-01  <S3: sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>          
2012-01-02  <S3: sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>          
2012-01-03  <S3: sfc_MULTIPOLYGON>
```

Comment: This solution seems nice and gets close to what I need. However, I'm not just comparing polygons across layers, but within shapefile layers as well. For example, I'm not just interested in knowing if a dissolved/overlapping polygon set had the earliest flood in 2012 vs. 2013; I'm also interested in knowing if the earliest polygon was dated in January 2012 vs. March 2012. Or even January 1st, 2012 vs. Jan 4th, 2012. Does your solution have an adaptable way to account for that as well?

Comment: Also, using your example, in the end, I would like to have 3 features of 4 fields with the polygons dissolved, rather than 18 features.

Comment: I update the answer above. I dont think that day instead of years would be a problem. And I put one example of ignoring ID and with union of every feature of a given day. Hope it helps.

Comment: I think this takes care of the second issue I had, so thank you for that! Now, the only problem is that in your solution each layer is receiving the same date, making it easy to programmatically determine which polygon goes on top based on the sequencing of the different layers. However, in my scenario I will have layers with a range of dates. For example, when I bring in the 2012 layer, it will have floods ranging from Jan to Dec. Then the same with the 2013 layer. So I will need to determine the earliest polygons within the layers, as well as between the different years.